# Pandas.loc() return empty values for unavailable indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ind,l1,l2 = [0,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1]
df = pd.DataFrame([ind,l1,l2],columns=[['C1','C2','C3']])
df.index=[['A','C','E']]
```

[image]

I want to use df.loc([['A','B','C','D','E']]) so that the unavailable indexes B & D returns nan values.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `loc` to `reindex`

```
df.reindex([['A','B','C','D','E']], axis=0)
```